# Office.js POST method gets converted to GET

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am developing Office web add-in. When I call external API using POST call from Home.js using the following function, even if the method is POST it automatically gets converted to GET while leaving from the browser (on the server side also GET request is received)  How to prevent this and post data using POST method?

Details:
Add-in development Env: Visual Studio 2017

```
function post(path, params) {
    var method = "POST";

    var form = document.createElement("form");

    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path); //path is HTTPS
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    console.log(form);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: What tool are you using that shows the Requests as GET? Fiddler?

Comment: @RickKirkham As "target" attribute is set to "_blank", after clicking on the button, it opens the link into new browser window of default browser. Network tab of the developer tools shows all the details about the request.

Comment: I think I might be reproducing this, but I'm not sure. The Network tab in F12 (Edge) is blank, but in Fiddler I see a GET to the `path`. Could  you share the URI you are passing as `path`? Also, what is your default browser?

Comment: I can not share the path as it is our internal dev servers. My default browser is Chrome.

Comment: Since you are using VS 2017, I assume you are developing on a Windows computer. Are you pressing F5 to test? If so, then Home.js should open in an IE based task pane. Or are you sideloading and testing on Office Online in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I use F5 to test. As target attribute in above code  is set to blank, upon clicking on the link the new window opens in my default browser which I have set as chrome in my Windows operating system's settings.

Comment: OK. I'll see if I can get some help internally in Microsoft.

Comment: Still trying to track down some help internally.

Comment: are you using http or https? most rewrite rule packages out there will do this if you try to use a post with http.